# Why are Alkaline, NiMH, and Li-ion AA measured differently (mAh, mWh, etc)?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, nimh, alkaline

Looking around Amazon, it seems that different types of batteries are measured differently:

Does anyone know why?

- Li-ion are measured in **mWh**

  - 1200mWh Cheap-Os
  - 3200mWh Deleepow
  - 3000mWh AmpTorrent
- NiMH are measured in **mAh**

  - 2000mAh Eneloop
  - 2800mAh EBL
- Alkalines are typically **not measured**

  - "Long Lasting" Duracell
  - "Longest Lasting" Energizer

I assume that **Alkalines** are not measured for some sort of historical reason with marketing departments?

... or is it that alkalines so mystical and unreliable that giving them a measurement is too aggressive? Or that switching to non-toxic / non-mercury was such a bad move in performance that measurements had to be removed in the 90s so people wouldn't know?

Perhaps **NiMH** are measured in mAh because the voltage can very so greatly and mWh doesn't make sense?

Are **Li-ion** measured in mWh because that's more consistent with non-battery measurements and they do deliver reliable voltage?